# What's the difference between admin_url() and get_admin_url() functions?

Tags: functions, wp-admin

Except for the `$blog_id` parameter (which is only allowed in the `get_admin_url` function), what is the difference between `admin_url` and `get_admin_url`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `admin_url()` function retrieves the URL to the admin area for your current site. You needn't give the blog id for your current site. You can use this function if you aren't running WordPress multisite. And use the `get_admin_url()` function to get a specific site URL in the multisite admin.

Answer (score 4):

### For single site installation:

Technically, except the `$blog_id` parameter, there isn't any difference at all.

[`admin_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/) function uses `get_admin_url` function internally with `$blog_id` parameter set to `null`. This is the source CODE of `admin_url` function:

```php
function admin_url( $path = '', $scheme = 'admin' ) {
    return get_admin_url( null, $path, $scheme );
}
```

And this is the function signature of [`get_admin_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_admin_url/) function:

```php
function get_admin_url( $blog_id = null, $path = '', $scheme = 'admin' )
```

So basically, calling `admin_url( $path, $scheme )` is the same as calling `get_admin_url( null, $path, $scheme )`.

### For multisite installation:

Since `admin_url()` doesn't support the `$blog_id` parameter, it's always used to get the **Admin URL** of the default blog (i.e. the current site you are accessing). However, if your WordPress is a **[multisite installation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/)**, and you need the **Admin URL** of another site within the same multisite network, then you'll need to use `get_admin_url( $blog_id )`.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the [old WP references](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_admin_url) (but not in the [new ones](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_admin_url/)), the only difference between the two functions is that <kbd>get_admin_url</kbd> allows the management of multi-site, thanks to the $blog_id parameter.